# Error while saving the workbook : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis-7, ms-office

I am creating an *excel file* with my *asp.net* application. I am hosting this site on *IIS7*.

When i run it from server, it is giving error while saving the workbook.

my code

```
Workbook.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Folder") + "\\" + filename + ".xls"
, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml, objOpt, objOpt, false, false
,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, objOpt, objOpt);
```

I have been trying to solve this for a week. hope I ll find some help here

This is my error

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

I am using *Office 2000,IIS7*. I have set all the authorizations.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Does the web application have permission to read/write to the location you're saving the file to?

Comment: yeah..It has permissions . . :(

Comment: From Google: Is the machine locale set to English (1033)?

Comment: Simply http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: @Ritch.. machine locale set to English

Comment: Have same issue connecting to Excel 2007 from VB.NET on local machine.

Answer (score 2):

**[Interop is not supported in sever-scenarios (like IIS) by MS](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2).**

There are many options to read/edit/create Excel files without Interop/installing Excel on the server:

MS provides the free OpenXML SDK V 2.0 - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx (XLSX only)

This can read+write MS Office files (including Excel).

Another free option see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OpenXML.aspx (XLSX only)

IF you need more like handling older Excel versions (like XLS, not only XLSX), rendering, creating PDFs, formulas etc. then there are different free and commercial libraries like [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX  only), [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) (free, XLSX only), [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx), [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/), [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set 'Read-Only' property to 'true' when opening the workbook ?

Refer following on how to open a workbook with write access :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = null;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text, 0, false, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
```

A value 'false' for 3rd parameter of 'xlApp.Workbooks.Open' method denotes that the workbook will not be read-only.

This is just a wild guess, since you have not shared any code about how you open a workbook. Hope it helps.